# remove case sensitivity from element ID before rule add?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

My registration form validates for valid email addresses and then attempts to match the submitted email's domain against a list of approved domain extenstions. It works, however the match rule will return an error if the submitted email domain contains a capitalized letter.

I've tried to add ".tolowercase()" to the element id (#s_email) but I can't get it to convert to lower case before it applies to the rule. Should I run the rule against a filtered variable?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.validator.addMethod('matches', function(value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || value.match(param);
    },'<?php _e('Please enter a valid email address.', 'reg_domain_check'); ?>');
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#s_email').rules("add", {matches: '<?php echo rdc_js_domain_list(); ?>', messages: {matches: '<?php _e('Sorry, your email address has not yet been approved for registration.', 'reg_domain_check'); ?>'}});
});
</script>
```

I've looked all over and can't find a solution for an element ID rule like above.

Comment: Did you write `.tolowercase()`, or [`.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)? I hope the irony of such a typo would not be lost on you. `:P`

Comment: what is param is it an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**.toLowerCase()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) where you are matching value .As you say it matches correct if the value is in lowercase so why not convert it lowecase and than match it.

change

```
value.match(param);
```

to

```
value.toLowerCase().match(param);
```

Now your code becomes

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.validator.addMethod('matches', function(value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || value.toLowerCase().match(param);
    },'<?php _e('Please enter a valid email address.', 'reg_domain_check'); ?>');
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#s_email').rules("add", {matches: '<?php echo rdc_js_domain_list(); ?>', messages: {matches: '<?php _e('Sorry, your email address has not yet been approved for registration.', 'reg_domain_check'); ?>'}});
});
</script
```

Comment: Thanks, Tushar. I was trying to append the element ID. I probably tried it once or twice as "tolowercase" as well.